# How to change event color face in emacs-calfw?

Tags: calendar

I have tried to change the default color faces of [emacs-calfw](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw), but I can't change the color of the event in date box.

I can change the `header` color, `grid` color, `button` color, but how to change the event color (pointed by arrow)

[image]

This is my code

```
(defun my-calendar ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (get-buffer "*cfw-calendar*")))
    (if buf
        (pop-to-buffer buf nil)
      (cfw:open-calendar-buffer
       :contents-sources
       (list (cfw:org-create-source "Dark Blue")
             (cfw:cal-create-source "Dark Orange"))
       :view 'two-weeks))))

(use-package calfw
  :bind ("C-c A" . my-calendar)
  :init
  (progn
    (use-package calfw-cal)
    (use-package calfw-org)
    (use-package calfw-ical)
    :config
    (progn
      (bind-key "g" 'cfw:refresh-calendar-buffer cfw:calendar-mode-map)
      (custom-set-faces
       '(cfw:face-title ((t (:foreground "#f0dfaf" :weight bold :height 2.0 :inherit variable-pitch))))
       '(cfw:face-header ((t (:foreground "#d0bf8f" :weight bold))))
       '(cfw:face-sunday ((t :foreground "#cc9393" :weight bold)))
       '(cfw:face-saturday ((t :foreground "8cd0d3"  :weight bold)))
       '(cfw:face-holiday ((t :background "grey10" :foreground "#8c5353" :weight bold)))
       '(cfw:face-grid ((t :foreground "#BADEAC")))
       '(cfw:face-default-content ((t :foreground "#ffffff")))
       '(cfw:face-periods ((t :foreground "#ffe259"))) ;;?
       '(cfw:face-day-title ((t :background "grey10"))) ;; rectangle in header
       '(cfw:face-default-day ((t :foreground "#ffffff" :weight bold :inherit cfw:face-day-title)))
       '(cfw:face-annotation ((t :foreground "#ffffff" :inherit cfw:face-day-title))) ;; data number in box(23 - 24)
       '(cfw:face-disable ((t :foreground "DarkGray" :inherit cfw:face-day-title)))
       '(cfw:face-today-title ((t :background "#7f9f7f" :weight bold)))
       '(cfw:face-today ((t :background: "grey10" :weight bold)))
       '(cfw:face-select ((t :background "#2f2f2f")))
       '(cfw:face-toolbar ((t :foreground "Steelblue4" :background "#3F3F3F")))
       '(cfw:face-toolbar-button-off ((t :foreground "#f5f5f5" :weight bold))) ;;top botton
       '(cfw:face-toolbar-button-on ((t :foreground "#ffffff" :weight bold)))))))
```

Comment: It is a little difficult for me to know for sure because I use a modified version of calfw where I have made quite a few revisions, but I do remember that it is possible to navigate using `M-x eval-expression` to place the cursor anywhere in the window, and from there you can type `C-u C-x =` and get the face.  Use things like `backward-char` and `forward-char` and `previous-line` and `next-line`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I can't select the content inside the box, just the the annotation face and title, I think [these](https://gist.github.com/azzamsa/97c3d5ce60e2a9305e58201958964d36) are only the available faces.

Comment: You can move the cursor anywhere inside the window using the guide in the previous comment above.  You will not be using the arrow keys or other usual methods to navigate the buffer -- i.e., you will strictly be using `M-:` aka `M-x eval-expression`.

Comment: You can also search for the word `defface` inside the source code to see all available faces:  https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/blob/master/calfw.el  If you like `M-x customize-group`, then you can look at `calfw` in that manner ...  If you are doing a lot of `:inherit`, then things may get a little confusing -- but, I have confidence you will figure it out.

Comment: Your second comment rocks, it solved. So what now ?, should I answer my own question?

Answer (score 1):

Since the color of the `calendar content` come from `cfw:org-create-source`, you have to pass color value as  an optional argument, if you leaved it empy, it will use default color which is `SaddleBrown`.

you can see the function of [cfw:cal-create-source](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw/blob/136dce009a26e7d8a8064af422c2cf8170e852c5/calfw-cal.el#L153)

```
(defun cfw:cal-create-source (&optional color)
  "Create diary calendar source."
  (make-cfw:source
   :name "calendar diary"
   :color (or color "SaddleBrown")
:data 'cfw:cal-schedule-period-to-calendar))
```

so you have to pass a color e.g

```
(cfw:org-create-source "Dark Blue")
(cfw:cal-create-source "White")
```

as what [jwiegley did](https://github.com/jwiegley/dot-emacs/blob/34af44f07752601c6f2d7019da38f6ebe5bb529b/dot-org.el#L830)